# nHibernate Mapping BaseClass to Multiple tables

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a group of objects that share some similar properties, so they inherit these from a base class. Here is a simple example of what I am doing.

I have 2 objects, `Employee` and `Customer` that have corresponding tables. Each contain a list of addresses. The `Address` class is shared between the two objects, but reside in two seperate tables `EmployeeAddress` and `CustomerAddress`.

```
EmployeeAddress - EmployeeId uniqueidentifier
                  Address varchar (50)
                  ZipCode varchar (10)
                  City varchar (20)
                  State id NOT NULL

CustomerAddress - CustomerId uniqueidentifier
                  Address varchar (50)
                  ZipCode varchar (10)
                  City varchar (20)
                  State id NOT NULL
```

How can I map my Address object to two seperate tables? I want it to be able to pull data from either the `EmployeeAddress` or `CustomerAddress` table when it needs to.

I have tried:

```
(EmployeeMap)
HasMany(x => x.Addresses).Table("EmployeeAddress").KeyColumn("EmployeeId");
```

But nHibernate complained that the `Address` class did not have its own mapping class.

```
(AddressMap)
Id(x => x.Id);
Map(x => x.ParentItemId);  //generic way to reference EmployeeId or CustomerId
                           // but I can't specify which column name it should 
                           //  actually be using
```

But nHIbernate tried grabbing data out of an `Address` table which doesn't exist, and my column names were wrong.

FYI: I will not be able to combine the two Address tables into one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create mappings that inherit from each other

Base mapping class that contains all the duplicated values:

```
public class AddressBaseMap<T> : ClassMap<T> where T : Address
{
    public AddressBaseMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Address);
        //etc
    }
}


public class CustomerAddressMap : AddressBaseMap<CustomerAddress>
{
    public CustomerAddressMap()
    {
        Table("CustomerAddress");
    }
}
```

I would also suggest the use of Components so that you can encapsulate all of the fields into a single class.